# BibTeX: referencing entire journal

Tags: bibtex, warnings

How can I write a BibTeX entry for a special issue of a journal? I've tried using `@book`, but then I get

```
Warning--can't use both volume and number fields in <entry>
```

I use `natbib` with `abbrvnat`, and I have the following fields for my entry:

- editor
- title
- publisher
- year
- volume
- number

Comment: This is a function of the bibliography style, not of BiBTeX itself.  If I use another bibstyle the warning doesn't arise, with a `@Book` entry.

Comment: use `@article` or `@proceedings` for this entry

Comment: @Herbert using `@proceedings` won't help here, since it also is formatted as a book volume, and disallows both volume and number in `abbrvnat.bst`. And `@article` isn't ideal either, since it expects an author field, not an editor field.

Answer (score 10):

[`biblatex`](http://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex) offers the entry type `@periodical` for a *"complete issue of a periodical, such as a special issue of a journal"* (manual, section 2.1.1).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{biblatex}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@periodical{Fis90,
  editor = {Fischel, William A.},
  year = {1990},
  title = {Land Economics},
  issuetitle = {Private Markets, Public Decisions: An Assessment of Local Land-Use Controls for the 1990s},
  volume = {66},
  number = {3},
  url = {http://www.jstor.org/stable/i357971},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\nocite{*}

\begin{document}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Comment: @Thomas (and others) should be aware that the `@periodical` entry type also exists in standard BiBTeX, but with a different semantics (essentially the same as `@article`) so this is truly a `biblatex`-only solution, and won't work with `natbib` at all.

Comment: @Alan: I re-checked Patashnik, *BibTeXing*, and Markey, *Tame the BeaST*, and neither source lists a `@periodical` type.

Comment: You're right.  I was making assumptions based on BibDesk, which I shouldn't have done.  So the basic point remains: this is a `biblatex`-only solution. (As you know; I'm just adding the comment for clarity.)

Answer (score 6):

Here's something quick-and-dirty I did (in standard Bibtex) in order to cite a special issue and it produced a result that was good for my purposes.

```
@book{JPhysABell2014,  
   title = {Special issue on 50 years of {B}ell's theorem},  
    author  =  {Journal of Physics A: Mathematical and Theoretical},  
  volume  = {47(42)},  
  month   = {October},  
  year    = {2014},  
  publisher = {IOP Science},  
  url     = { -- OMITTED -- },  
  note    = {\url{  -- OMITTED -- }}  
}  
% Volume 47, Number 42, 24 October 2014
```

[[I had remove the url's so that the tex.stackexchange session manager would allow me to post this.]]

Here's the result it produced with the "plain" bibliography style.

> [17] Journal of Physics A: Mathematical and Theoretical. Special issue
>   on 50 years of Bell's theorem, volume 47(42). IOP Science, October
>   2014.    http://iopscience.iop.org/1751-8121/47/42.

Where the title "Special issue on 50 years of Bell's theorem" was emphasized (in italics).

Comment: Using this method, `volume={18 Issue 3}` produced `Volume 18 Issue 3`.

Answer (score 4):

If it's a special issue that happens to be the proceedings of a conference, then there is the `@proceedings` type which (according to emacs reftex) takes the following arguments:

```
@Proceedings{foo,
  title =    {},
  year =     {},
  OPTkey =   {},
  OPTbooktitle = {},
  OPTeditor =    {},
  OPTvolume =    {},
  OPTnumber =    {},
  OPTseries =    {},
  OPTaddress =   {},
  OPTmonth =     {},
  OPTorganization = {},
  OPTpublisher = {},
  OPTnote =      {},
  OPTannote =    {}
}
```

Note the optional ones are prefaced by `OPT` and you will need to remove the `OPT` and all the fields you are not using to get this to work.

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem.  The issue is not with the entry-type or the available fields, it's with the way the `abbrvnat.bst` style decides to format those entries.  The @Book entry has basically the same fields.

Answer (score 4):

I found that online bibtex snippets are often faulty. Especially for `inproceedings`, the `number` may actually be `issue`.

Example:

Google scholar snippet:

```
@inproceedings{berchtold1998pyramid,
  title={The pyramid-technique: towards breaking the curse of dimensionality},
  author={Berchtold, Stefan and B{\"o}hm, Christian and Kriegal, Hans-Peter},
  booktitle={ACM SIGMOD Record},
  volume={27},
  number={2},
  pages={142--153},
  year={1998},
  organization={ACM}
}
```

However, according to [ACM](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=276318) it is:

Volume 27 Issue 2, June 1998
Pages 142-153

Comment: But how do you specify the issue? I am not sure about what is the right bibtex field. Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is no 'issue' field. For the example, apparently ACM changed it to use 'number' instead of 'issue'.

Comment: You can also write text in the field. `volume={18 Issue 3}` produced `Volume 18 Issue 3` for me using Overleaf BibTeX and `natbib`.

Comment: I just change `number` to `issue` and leave everything else untouched, it does the trick, no warning anymore

Answer (score 0):

Further to answer [#4 above](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21946/bibtex-referencing-entire-journal#answer-337437) (this won't fit as a comment) some notes to help those trying to address this issue and using as ACM's `acmart` package. (As I write, I'm trying to write better docs due to author's complaints in the ACM Conference where I submit—so this on my desk right now)

Sadly the ACM style is poorly documented. The basic [style page](https://www.acm.org/publications/authors/reference-formatting) doesn't explain the part of a reference and conflicts with the supposed [BibTeX versions](https://www.acm.org/publications/authors/bibtex-formatting). The cited items differ and some BibTeX code either won't compile or used the wrong field for `acmart'. At the same time, DL.ACM doesn't appear to use ACM styles (as per the style guide) or the attendant BibTeX.

Though `acmart` can be configured (by an expert user) to use `BibLaTeX` processing, it uses `natbib` by default—and the documents seems to assume that too. The `acmart` BST file defines a custom `@periodical` type, though ACM style pages do not document the approved output style of that (I've not tested how the ACM and BiBLaTeX `@periodical` do/don't align).

Asking for a citation of Communications of The ACM Volume 50, Issue 1, DL.ACM's offered BibTeX is this:

```
@article{10.1145/1188913,
year = {2007},
issue_date = {January 2007},
publisher = {Association for Computing Machinery},
volume = {50},
number = {1},
issn = {0001-0782},
journal = {Commun. ACM}
}
```

which compiles with errors (missing fields) and is the wrong type anyway. Using the `acmart` @periodical and dumping fields unused for actual referencing we get:

```
@periodical{jcacm,
    year = {2007},
    volume = {50},
    number = {1},
    journal = {Commun. ACM}
}
```

That errors on compile (I'm using Overleaf and `acmart` 1.9.2) for having no title and for no editor or organization. This does work:

```
@periodical{jcacm,
    year = {2007},
    organization = {Association for Computing Machinery},
    editor = {Diane Crawford},
    volume = {50},
    number = {1},
    title = {January 2007},
    journal = {Commun. ACM}
}
```

Note that if both editor and organization are supplied, only editor is used. I had to trawl the magazine's front-matter to find the editor: most people might want to just use the org name instead, being less effort.

Now, at last, the point about styling the issue number. The default ACM-supplied code is:

```
    volume = {50},
    number = {1},
```

or we can substitute an 'issue' field for 'number'

```
    volume = {50},
    issue = {1},
```

or leverage the fact (uncodumented formally) the 'volume' data is used verbatim

```
    volume = {50 Issue 1},
```

This, on order as above, output like:

Diane Crawford (Ed.). 2007. January 2007. Commun. ACM 50, 1 (2007).

Diane Crawford (Ed.). 2007. January 2007. Commun. ACM 50 (2007).

Diane Crawford (Ed.). 2007. January 2007. Commun. ACM 50 Issue 1 (2007).

So whilst an 'issue' field works in some types, it doesn't get used at all in ACM's version of `@pereiodical`.

Now, compare this with the first two lines of content on the Issue's [page at DL.ACM](https://dl.acm.org/toc/cacm/2007/50/1). Line #1 uses "Vol. 50, No. 1" and line #2 uses "Volume 50, Issue 1". The first is akin to variant #1 above, and the second to variant #3. Going with variant #1 makes most sense as it doesn't need editing of the 'volume' field which might mess up use of the same code for other output (publisher) styles.

So unless/until the ACM steadies on a stated preference, close enough is probably good enough for referencing. Sigh.

One other ACM BibTeX 'gotcha' is access dates for online references. natbib pre-dates the we so has no notion of URL-based online resources. `acmart` maps `@online` to `@misc` type but **doesn't** support the now general use of the `urldate` field for the access data. Instead, ACM accepts such dates only a custom field `lastaccessed`. An alternative hack is to put the access dates in the 'note' field.

Hopefully that saves some others a lot of wasted time trying to fix their BibTeX for ACM submissions.